# function if in while block in language C

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

someone could help,
I trying to code, a program to read a char, and output 1 to lower char, 2 to Upper and -1 if it's not a letter. The program should keep working until the input be a Zero

I can't understand why the following code;
keeping print -1 in all situations of the "if" block;

I try two ways:

**first try**:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char entrada = 'x';
    
    while (entrada != 48) {
        scanf("%c", &entrada);
            
        if (entrada > 96 && entrada < 123) {
            printf("%d\n", 1);
        } else if (entrada > 64 && entrada < 91) {
            printf("%d\n", 2); 
        } else {
            printf("%d\n", -1);
        }     
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**second try**:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char entrada = 'x';
    int teste;
    
    while (entrada != 48){
        scanf("%c", &entrada);
            
        if (entrada > 96 && entrada <123){
            printf("%d\n", 1);
            continue;
        } else {
            if (entrada > 64 && entrada < 91) {
                printf("%d\n", 2);
                continue;
            } else if (entrada <= 64 || (entrada >= 91 && entrada <= 96) 
                       || entrada >= 123 ) {
                printf("%d\n", -1);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never use 64, 91, 96, 123, or other numbers for characters unless you are actually implementing code that defines or translates between character sets. It is hard to read, easy to make a mistake, and needless non-portable. Even if you are assuming ASCII, use code such as `entrada >= 'a' && entrada <= 'z'`. Generally, you should also include `<ctype.h>` and use `islower((unsigned char) entrada)` and `isupper((unsigned char) entrada)` rather than doing `entrada >= 'a' && entrada <= 'z'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your program (either of them) executes `scanf("%c", &entrada);`, `scanf` reads a single character.

When you type “a” and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>, two characters are sent to your program: “a” and a new-line character.

When your program reads “a“, it prints “1”.

When your program reads the new-line character, it prints “-1”.

So, as long as you enter a character and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>, your program prints two numbers: one for the first character and one for the new-line character.

Comment: Thanks !  Now I could solve, I just put in the last Else  input !=  10 (new line)